# How to mount ext3,ext4 sitting on VDI VirtualBox HDD?

Tags: mount, partition, virtualbox

How to mount ext3, ext4 partition sitting on "Fixed-Size VDI" VirtualBox HardDisk ?

To be more specific, I ma interested in case when VM is not running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found very helpful answer on:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Mounting_.vdi_Images

The tip is to use `offset` option of ext4 mount (to be more specific, in back scenes it uses `offset` as option for loopback device `losetup`)

It's about

- taking `offData` info from VDI image
- adding magic number 32256
- and using result as offset

Here is my way of automating it:

```
VDIfile=VirtData.vdi
mountingpoint=/mnt/VDI
offData=$( VBoxManage internalcommands dumphdinfo "$VDIfile" |grep offData | sed 's:.*offData=\([0-9]*\).*:\1:' )
offset=$(( $offData + 32256 ))
mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime,noexec,loop,offset="$offset" "$VDIfile" "$mountingpoint"
```

For `/etc/fstab` you might like to add: (`123456789` is counted previously offset)

```
/path/VirtData.vdi      /mnt/VDI        ext4 rw,noatime,noexec,loop,offset=123456789,user,noauto
```

Of course `rw` can be changed to `ro` or you might not need `noatime` or `noexec` - taylor them to your needs

Btw. if your path contains spaces there is a trick of changing `spaces` into `\040` (source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab )

Answer (score 4):

The package `virtualbox-fuse` installs the `vdfuse` command which can be used to mount either dynamic or fixed VDI files.

```
apt-get install virtualbox-fuse
mkdir /mnt/point
mkdir /mnt/p1
vdfuse -f file.vdi /mnt/point
mount /mnt/point/Partition1 /mnt/p1
```